# Sim card issues

Tags: applications, samsung

I have a samsung j1 ace sm-j111m

If I start it without a sim installed it doesn't display the 'no sim' warning

If I start it with a sim installed it doesn't change the top icon for a sim being installed.

I've tried the online guides, ping tests fail and no luck 
 I've tried using the sim card info app and it discovers the sim info and voicemail notifications come up

Thoughts? Possible fixes?

Comment: Hardware issue probably? Or is this phone locked to a particular network?

Comment: I'm beginning to think that but it's not locked as the code screen doesn't come up with any screen so I'm assuming it isn't locked to any network

Comment: Sometimes the lock screen doesnt come up. But okay let think it's hardware related then.

Comment: I'm not really sure but as the sim card info app reads the card data I don't think it's hardware. I think it has to do with whatever part of the Droid os has to deal with detecting no sim card installed

Comment: Can you check if IMEI is still present (*#06#)? I'm starting to think there might be something wrong  with the modem.

Comment: Imei and sn still present...I checked already

Comment: You should bring it to a repair shop, they should be able to fix that for you.

Comment: I've gotten the troubleshooting manual for it and it seems the problem is a fuse ic...can you help me find a replacement?  Google has been less than helpful the code is swv grh66

Comment: I don't think you are able to do such technical things. Why don't you bring it to a repair shop?

Comment: No one in my country does any board level repairs

Comment: No one? Okay. You should ask for help here: http://gsmhosting.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed a custom rom? Sometimes custom roms can give this sort of problem. If you are using a custom rom revert back to the stock rom.

Comment: I've re flashed 2 different versions of the stock rom and no luck

Comment: Was it for your own model? I had the same problem when I flashed an update for devices based on UK and around that region.

Comment: Yes correct model but I've no way of telling it's original country so I flashed all the roms for my country and no luck

Comment: Did you create a nandroid backup of your original stock rom? If so you can restore your system using it.

Comment: No I haven't it's been doing this since I've gotten the phone second hand

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: If not what you need to do s search for a proper compatible custom rom for your device and then flash it. Don't use custom roms that have been made for other devices but have specs same to yours.

Comment: I have been using stock roms all along